# Error "unsendable" when passing SendPort to Isolate.spawn()

Tags: dart

This is a piece of code I have written:

```
class IsolateTask {
  final String _name;
  final ReceivePort _eventReceivePort; // Port for receiving events from isolate.
  Isolate? _isolate;

  IsolateTask(String name, ReceivePort eventReceivePort)
      : _name = name,
        _eventReceivePort = eventReceivePort,
        _isolate = null;

  String get name => _name;

  Future<void> start() async {
    final eventSendPort = _eventReceivePort.sendPort;
    print('Runtime type of eventReceivePort is ${_eventReceivePort.runtimeType}');
    print('Runtime type of eventSendPort is ${eventSendPort.runtimeType}');
    _isolate = await Isolate.spawn<SendPort>(entryPoint, eventSendPort, errorsAreFatal: true, debugName: _name);
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

The two print statements output the following, which is what I expect:

```
Runtime type of eventReceivePort is _ReceivePortImpl
Runtime type of eventSendPort is _SendPort
```

But nevertheless, I get an Exception:

*Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable - Library:'dart:isolate' Class: _ReceivePortImpl@1026248 (see restrictions listed at `SendPort.send()` documentation for more information)*

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Windows 11

VsCode 1.85.1

Dart SDK version: 3.2.0-134.0.dev ... on "windows_x64"

EDIT: The purpose here is to encapsulate in a class (or a set of classes) a mechanism where one or more concurrent tasks perform long-term activities, directed by the main task, and reporting back whatever events are significant for the overall logic. The context where I may be going to use this is an industrial control system. A set of concurrent tasks control various sub-systems, while the main task is a state machine that handles all the events the sub-systems generate, and behaves consequently.

Comment: Where are `entryPoint` defined and what does it point to? Also, since you are using VSCode, I want to ask you if you have made sure to save your program before running it?

Comment: @julemand101 `entryPoint` is a member function of `IsolateTask`, receiving a `SendPort`, and then issuing its own `SendPort` to the main isolate, in order to establish a two-way communication. I have tried to simplify the code to a minimum, in order to edit the OP with more details, but now it works. So I am now adding back piece by piece in order to spot when and where it fails.

Comment: @julemand101 I am running my code directly inside VSCode (Run -> Run without debugging, or Run -> Start debugging). Modifications are automatically saved before the code is run. I have double-checked this.

Comment: Update: I read through this documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.4/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawn.html, and it says *If entryPoint is a closure then it may implicitly send unexpected state to the isolate due to limitations in the Dart implementation*. So I began suspecting that the problem was related to the entryPoint function being a member function. By moving it outside the class, thus making it a top-level function, the exception is no longer thrown. Now I have some more details to fix, then hopefully I will be able to report the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP problem, per se, is easily solved by making `entryPoint` a top-level function, or as in the following code, a static function. So, apparently, the exception text was misleading, and the problem was not with the port type.

Anyway, I am posting here a more complete (experimental) code sample, that also illustrates how I am trying to achieve the purpose that is stated in the OP edit.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

class TaskMessage {}

class StopTask extends TaskMessage {}

class TaskEvent {}

abstract class EventConsumer {
  void handleEvent(TaskEvent event);
}

abstract class TaskLogic {
  SendPort? eventSendPort;
  void handleMessage(TaskMessage message);
  void sendEvent(TaskEvent event) => eventSendPort?.send(event);
}

class IsolateTask {
  final TaskLogic logic;
  final EventConsumer consumer;
  final ReceivePort eventReceivePort;
  SendPort? messageSendPort;

  IsolateTask(this.logic, this.consumer) : eventReceivePort = ReceivePort();

  Future<void> start() async {
    Completer completer = Completer<SendPort>();

    eventReceivePort.listen((event) {
      if (event is SendPort) {
        completer.complete(event);
      } else {
        consumer.handleEvent(event);
      }
    });

    await Isolate.spawn<(SendPort, TaskLogic)>(entryPoint, (eventReceivePort.sendPort, logic));
    messageSendPort = await completer.future;
  }

  void stop() => messageSendPort?.send(StopTask());

  void sendMessage(TaskMessage message) => messageSendPort?.send(message);

  static void entryPoint((SendPort, TaskLogic) param) {
    var eventSendPort = param.$1;
    var logic = param.$2;
    logic.eventSendPort = eventSendPort;
    var isolatedMessageReceivePort = ReceivePort();
    eventSendPort.send(isolatedMessageReceivePort.sendPort);

    isolatedMessageReceivePort.listen((message) {
      if (message is StopTask) {
        exit(0);
      } else {
        logic.handleMessage(message);
      }
    });
  }
}

class MyMessage extends TaskMessage {
  String content;
  MyMessage(this.content);
  @override
  String toString() => content;
}

class MyEvent extends TaskEvent {
  String content;
  MyEvent(this.content);
  @override
  String toString() => content;
}

class MyTaskLogic extends TaskLogic {
  @override
  void handleMessage(TaskMessage message) {
    print('[Task] Received $message');
    sendEvent(MyEvent('from task'));
  }
}

class MyMainLogic implements EventConsumer {
  late IsolateTask task;

  Future<void> run() async {
    task = IsolateTask(MyTaskLogic(), this);
    await task.start();
    task.sendMessage(MyMessage('from main'));
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(TaskEvent event) {
    print('[Main] Received $event');
    task.stop();
  }
}

void main() async {
  var mainLogic = MyMainLogic();
  await mainLogic.run();
}
```

Some explanations:

- `TaskMessage`: base class for *messages* the main task can send to the isolate task
- `StopTask`: a specific message, telling the isolate task to stop (exit)
- `TaskEvent`: base class for *events* the isolate task can send to the main task
- `EventConsumer`: interface for the main logic, consuming events
- `TaskLogic`: base class for the isolate task logic, receving messages to direct its actions and behaviour, and sending back whatever events might be significant to the main task
- `IsolateTask`: encapsulates the logic for isolate creation, and for message and event delivery
- `MyMessage`, `MyEvent`: two example *message* and *event* classes
- `MyTaskLogic`: example isolate task logic, just bouncing back messages
- `MyMainLogic`: example main task logic, that starts the isolate task, the sends it a message, and when the message is bounced back as an event, stops the isolate task.

Output:

```
[Task] Received from main
[Main] Received from task

Exited.
```

**Credit**: I have learnt some important details, especially the use of the `Completer`, from this example, by *lmzach09*: https://gist.github.com/lmzach09/147236158999f2e5a5a75e469f9cba3c

**See also**: This article by *Plague Fox* contains extremely useful examples and insight about Dart isolates, that I actually plan to take into account to improve my code: https://plugfox.dev/mastering-isolates/